# Dizziness occurred right after I~ VS Dizziness happened VS Dizziness developed

Tags: meaning

Not in written english but in casual conversation, 
which one is the most natural one to native?

Comment: Welcome to our site. If you haven't already done so, I recommend you take the **[Tour]**. You might also find our sibling site [ell.se] useful. :-)

Comment: None of them is very natural in normal conversation. Something like “I started feeling dizzy right after I went into the sauna” would be a much more natural way of phrasing it.

Answer (score 1):

These don't sound normal at the beginning of a sentence because dizziness is something that a person experiences. In order to use the word 'dizziness' there has to be someone experiencing the dizziness, who is usually going to be the subject of the sentence. It's also normal to include a verb that has 'dizziness' as it's object, like 'feel' or 'experience'.

> I started to experience dizziness when I reached the top of the ladder
>
> I felt some dizziness after my second drink.

One situation where you could use 'Dizziness occurred' or 'Dizziness developed' would be in a general description of a response that is not referring to a specific instance of dizziness. For instance, in a medical study. In this case there will be a prepositional phrase in the sentence describing who experienced the dizziness.

> Dizziness developed after a period of five minutes for most subjects.
>
> In my case, dizziness occurs every time I spin myself around and around.

Another situation where a similar construction would be appropriate would be if you had already mentioned the dizziness.

> I had been feeling dizziness all day. The dizziness happened every time I stood up.

In cases where the construction is appropriate, any of those three verbs (occurred, developed, happened) sounds normal. 'Developed' could mean that it happened gradually, getting worse over time, and the other two are synonymous.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Dwilli, it complicates the phrase to make the dizziness sound second hand and objective. It can be compared to happy. I felt happiness develop... etc. dizzy is a good word. In received English, they would say "a sense of dizziness enveloped him, felt a dizzy sensation, became dizzy, a peculiar sense of dizziness".